# Increase font size in Adobe Acrobat Pro

Tags: windows-7, adobe-acrobat

I have a PDF that I got by converting a web page to PDF.

Adobe won't let me select all text (which would let me increase the font size).  The annoying part is that I am able to open each object individually, and increase the text size that way, but I have thousands of objects)

Please excuse my terminology, if I am unclear, just specify, and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Try to open it and to hold "Ctrl" key at the same timeyou roll up the central scroll buttom on ou mouse with your mouse pointer inside the pdf area.

Comment: Doesn't change anything.  Doesn't let me select more than one object at a time, and when the object is selected, I can't edit the font, its all grayed out.

Comment: Why do you want to increase the text size object by object rather than just zooming the entire PDF?

Comment: I'll be sending it to someone else, and don't want to have them think to enlarge it.

Comment: @afrazier Please post an answer, the one you gave in your comment is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acrobat lets you save a default zoom level (part of the PDF properties, which seem to move from version to version).

Another option would be to increase the text size of the source web page and then converting that to PDF.  You may have to use Acrobat's "Print to PDF" feature rather than creating a PDF from a website (by providing the URL to Acrobat or with the web browser add-in) for this to work.

Finally, Acrobat's "create PDF from web page" settings does let you set the base font size.  That may work, depending on how the web page is designed.